# Question on discontinuities when denominator has roots but factors out with numerator.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Two questions and the answers that I came across have shaken my fundamental concepts of continuity.
They are as follows:

$$f(x) = \frac{4-x^2}{4x-x^3}$$
$$h(x) = \frac{(x^2-4)(x-1)}{x^2-a}$$

a. $f(x)$ after factorization reduces to simply $1/x$.

Does that mean it only has one single point of discontinuity at $x =0$  ?
Or will all the points where the denominator equals to 0 which are $x = -2 , \ 0 ,\  2$  be considered as points of discontinuity?

b. The second question about $h(x)$ asks for the number of values of $a$ for which the function $h(x)$ will be continuous at all values of $x$ ? The answer is given to be that exactly one value of $a$ exists such that the function will be continuous at all $x$. How is that possible ? That means they are not including the points where denominator goes to $0$.

Do we always include points where denominator = $0$ in points of discontinuity regardless of whether they get factored out by the denominator or not ? or is that not the case ?

Comment: $f(x)$ is not defined when $x\in\{-2,0,2\}$

Comment: So are these points considered points of discontinuity for the function ?

Comment: $f$ is a differnent fucntion than $g(x)=\frac1 x$ in that the latter is defined (and continous) at $\pm2$ whereas the former is not. The fact that $f(x)=g(x)$  whenever $f$ is defined doesn't suddenly make $f$ defined where $g$ is defined.  $\pm2$ are called *removable* singularities because we can extend $f$ to $g$ nicely . -- For b) I would not call $h$ continuous (or even defined) at $\pm2$ when we let $a=4$. However, $h$ can in that case be uniquely *extended* to a continuous function on all of $\Bbb R$. In a strict context, $h$ and its extension remain different functions though

Comment: Concluding from the *intended* answer to b) it appears that your textbook considers points where a function is not defined, but into which it can be extended continuously, *not* as points of idscontinuity.

Comment: But what is the formal way it is considered in mathematics: are points where function is not defined considered as points of discontinuity ?

Comment: @DivyeshShah No. For instance, the function $x\to1/x$ is continuous (everywhere on its domain). A point of discontinuity is necessarily part of the domain of the function. See also [Classification of discontinuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes but in the function $1/x$ the L.H.L. is not equal to R.H.L. at x=0. Hence it is an infinite discontinuity, but for example in f(x) that I have statement in the questions, the RHL=LHL, hence it is simply a hole discontinuity.

Comment: As I wrote below under Hello's answer, 0 is then not a discontinuity, but a singularity. A function is continuous or discontinuous only in its domain. Outside of its domain, it makes no sense. A function is given by a domain $A$, a range $B$ and a subset of $A\times B$. You can't tell anything about the function on some object $x$ not in $A$. It's tempting when $A$ is $\Bbb R \backslash \{x_1,\dots ,x_n\}$, but you can't either.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ will be discontinuous at all values where the denominator evaluates to 0 because it is not defined at those values. Remember the definition of continuity at a point $a$ is that $f(x)$ is equal to the limit as $x $approaches $ a$.

For you second question, $h(x)$ will always be continuous (for real values of $x$) if and only if $a $is negative (because then the denominator will never reach 0). In contrast, if a is positive, the quadratic on the bottom will certainly have two roots, or if it is 0, it will have one. Obviously this is only considering real numbers...

Comment: If the function is not defined, it's not a [discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities), it's a [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)).

Comment: If the function is not define, then by definition it cannot be continuous at that point

Comment: The formal definition of continuity implies that a function cannot be continuous at a point not in the functions domain. Obviously, I am not contesting the fact that it is also possible for a discontinuity to occur at a point in the domain...